# How to observe simple variable in dart language

Tags: dart, dart-webui

My question is: How to observe changes on simple variable like String or num?
I know that you can easy observe object like this:

```
observe(t, (e) => print ("Value changed"));
```

but How to do this on simple variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This answer applies to Polymer.dart.)

The `observe` package includes a wrapper for single observable values: `ObservableBox`.

```dart
import 'package:observe/observe.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  ObservableBox myValue = new ObservableBox('hello');

  myValue.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> records) {
    PropertyChangeRecord record = records[0] as PropertyChangeRecord;

    print('${record.field} changed, it is now ${myValue.value}');
  });

  new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
    myValue.value = new DateTime.now();
  });
}
```

There is no way to observe a top-level or function-scope single string, boolean, int, or double without using ObservableBox.

If the string, boolean, int, or double is a field of a class, you can use `ObservableMixin` and the `@observable` annotation.

```dart
class Foo extends Object with ObservableMixin {
  @observable String bar = '';
}
```

You can then get notified when an instance of Foo changes:

```dart
foo.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> records) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: It appears that currently (SDK 1.6) it's name rather than field, and oldValue and newValue. However, name is a Symbol, and so record.name == "myProperty" won't evaluate. Hrm.

Comment: So record.name == "myProperty" needs to be converted to a String using mirrors. See my answer and code below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the binding of a string value that is object attribute:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <template id="_template" bind>
      <input type="text" value="{{name}}">
      <p>The name is {{name}}</p>
    </template>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class Person extends Object with ObservableMixin {
  @observable
  String name;
  Person(this.name);
}

main() {
  query("#_template").model = new Person('Bob');
}
```