# on-change event not firing properly when binding value

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have this html code:

```dart
<textarea id="text-to-convert" on-change="change" value="{{text}}"></textarea>
```

And this dart code:

```dart
import "dart:html";
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('dictionary-converter')
class DictionaryConverter extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {

  @observable String text = "Initial text";

  void change(Event event, var detail, TextAreaElement textElement) {
    print(textElement.value);
    print(text);
  }

}
```

In this case, the `on-change` event is only triggered from time to time. (I haven't yet figured out when exactly).

When I remove the `value={{text}}` binding, the event is properly fired every time the textare is changed.

Am I overlooking something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Polymer 0.8+ you can use *yourFieldName**Changed. When the observed property changes, the `Changed` method will be called. Since `String text` is two way data bound, changing the value of the textarea will change the value of `String text` and call the `textChanged` method. This works with your original code and doesn't need `ObservableBox`

```dart
import "dart:html";
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('dictionary-converter')
class DictionaryConverter extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {

  @observable String text = "Initial text";

  textChanged(oldValue) {
    print("textarea: ${this.shadowRoot.query("textarea").value}");
    print("text: ${text}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have to use an `ObservableBox` as described [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18545589/170851)

So I ended up with:

```dart
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";
import "package:observe/observe.dart";

@CustomTag('dictionary-converter')
class DictionaryConverter extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {

  ObservableBox csvText = new ObservableBox("Initial text");

  ready() {
    csvText.changes.listen(convert);
  }

  void convert(x) {
    String text = csvText.value;
  }

}
```